# Django model list order field update

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table, let's say `Book`, with the following model definition:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of the book', max_length=10)
    sequence = models.IntegerField('The order for the book')
```

I need to show the `Book` list order by `sequence` field as follow, and the sequence value would be 1, 2, 3, etc...

```
Book.objects.all().order_by('sequence')
```

But I am getting stuck when creating/updating a book instance in the view. I am not quite sure how to `re-sequence` the existing books when inserting a new book model or updating an existing one.

Suppose, I already got three books in the database, let's say:

```
BookA, sequence = 1
BookB, sequence = 2
BookC, sequence = 3
```

When I insert a new one, named **BookD** with sequence **1**, I need to update the existing ones to assign a new sequence value for each book already in the database. My expected result would be:

```
BookD, sequence = 1
BookA, sequence = 2
BookB, sequence = 3
BookC, sequence = 4
```

So does anyone know how to do this in Django? Example code is really appreciated.

Comment: You can get same implemented functionality from https://github.com/incuna/django-orderable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first filter all the books with sequence greater than sequence number you are inserting and increment the sequence number of those books by 1. And, then save the new book:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(sequence__gte=bookD.sequence)
books.update(sequence=F('sequence')+1)
bookD.save()
```

---

In case, `bookD` is already created then you could exclude it before updating the `sequence`:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(sequence__gte=bookD.sequence).exclude(pk=bookD.pk)
books.update(sequence=F('sequence')+1)
```